# LibreOffice convert-to pdf produces file could not be loaded error even if file has 777 permissions

Tags: php, ubuntu, pdf, libreoffice

I migrated a site for a client recently and have been having trouble with LibreOffice. One feature of the site takes a docx, makes changes to it, then copies it and converts it into a pdf for user download. For some reason I can't get the edited file that needs to be changed to a pdf to be properly accessed by libreoffice.

For example if in terminal I attempt to run:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf edited_source.docx edited_pdf.pdf --outdir /storage
```

I get the error:

```
Error: source file could not be loaded
```

I am definitely using the correct path, and I attempted to even set `chmod 777 edited_source.docx` for testing purposes (would of course not leave it 777) but even so, it cannot be loaded.

Any ideas what I'm missing? Could I be missing a package?

EDIT: I have also checked the docx files that are being converted to make sure they are not corrupted, they seem to be opening fine in word etc, and I have also made sure that libreoffice-writer is installed

EDIT: I am using Ubuntu 20.04.01 and libreoffice 6.4.6.2

Comment: Does LibreOffice load the docx in the GUI?

Comment: There is no gui, it is headless on the server I'm calling the script in php

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of this. Can't you login to the server and start it with GUI? Another idea: a docx file is just a ZIP file. Did you try to list its contents with a ZIP tool?

Comment: @movac did you solve this?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? How is this related to PHP?

Answer (score 17):

If you installed libreoffice using this command
`sudo apt-get install libreoffice-common` then you should also install the libreoffice writer in order to convert docx files to pdf

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-writer
```